# JavaScript seemingly loaded into DOM but won't execute until run in chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this JavaScript for a text-search link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.magnifying-glass').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
       url: '/search',
      data: $('#nav-search-form').serialize()
    })
  });
});
```

I can view this is in my sources tab within `search.js` and in my `<head>..</head>` section I have:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-d456baa54c1fa6be2ec3711f0a72ddf7a5b2f34a6b4f515f33767d6207b7d4b3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/search.self-2cca0e1f96075e050d52df6946570db92431ae8071b63b90c85460b3502d0560.js?body=1"></script>
```

However, the JavaScript does not appear to be executing. I had hoped it would be a problem with the JavaScript itself, but if this JavaScript is copied and pasted into the Chrome console and run then it appears to be doing its job (i.e. the search form is serialized, an AJAX request is sent and search results are returned when the icon is clicked).

It might be worth mentioning that the `<div>` element on which the event handler is bound is:

```
<div class="icon icon--ei-search icon--m magnifying-glass l-inline-block l-fl">
      <svg class="icon__cnt">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ei-search-icon"></use>
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that that `<div>` is part of the page when the "ready" handler runs?

Comment: I assumed so, but how could I check for sure?

Comment: not only does the div exist, does it have the `magnifying-glass` class

Comment: @oliverwillder - to see if the div is there and correctly classed, try `console.log($('.magnifying-glass').length);` in the document ready block

Comment: @JaromandaX To test the hypothesis that the script is being run too early I inserted a script tag beneath the div to which the handler is bound and ran the script in there. This works, so previously it must have been run before the div and/or existed, but this solution is not lovely html, can you think of another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is due to the `.magnifying-glass` element not existing when your script runs.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will tell you if the element exists!
    console.log($('.magnifying-glass').length);
    $('.magnifying-glass').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
             url: '/search',
             data: $('#nav-search-form').serialize()
        });
    });
});
```

Check your console. If `0` is printed, `.magnifying-glass` does not exist. To solve this problem attach the click listener to the body, and delegate the event to `.magnifying-glass`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.magnifying-glass', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
             url: '/search',
             data: $('#nav-search-form').serialize()
        });
    });
});
```

(For clarification: If some number greater than zero is printed, I've failed to answer your question!!)

Comment: The result was 0. This could be due to the fact that the div to which the event handler is bound is also loaded via AJAX (I forgot to say this before). I changed `.click(...` to `.on('click'...` but this had no effect, (seemingly as the former is just a shortcut for the latter according to the docs: https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: The important part is attaching the click handler to `body`, and making the 2nd parameter of `on` be `'.magnifying-glass'`. This attaches the listener to the html body (which is guaranteed to exist when your js runs), and causes the `body` element to delegate events to anything matching the selector that is the 2nd param - you missed part of my answer!

Comment: Sorry, yes I did miss your point, this is a better soloution than I posted below. Attaching a listener to something that is already there is much cleaner than using an extra .js.erb template. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this problem was running:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('.magnifying-glass').length);
});
```

(Please see Gershom Maes' answer, full credit goes to him).

Since the logged result was `0` it proved that `<div class="magnifying-glass">...</div>` on which the event listener was being registered did not exist at the time the relevant JavaScript was being run.

The reason for this was that `<div class="magnifying-glass">...</div>` was loaded by AJAX after the initial DOM was loaded.

Therefore the solution was to put:

```
$('.magnifying-glass').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/search',
    data: $('#nav-search-form').serialize()
  })
});
```

in the .js.erb template that loaded `<div class="magnifying-glass">...</div>` so that the script would run at the appropriate time, as follows:

```
$('<%= j(render('shared/nav_searchbar')) %>').insertAfter('#home-link');

# (above) partial that contains <div class="magnifying-glass">...</div> 

$('.magnifying-glass').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/search',
    data: $('#nav-search-form').serialize()
  })
});
```

**UPDATE**

While the above solution does work it fails to recognize the second half of Gershom Maes' answer above which is simpler and stresses the difference between registering a .click(function() {...}) event listener on `<div class="magnifying-glass">...</div>` and registering an on('click', '.magnifying-glass', function() {...}) event listener on the `<body>...</body>` which will wait for the `<div class="magnifying-glass">...</div>` to appear in the DOM after it is loaded via AJAX.